# IIS Express worker process has stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-7

I am having a problem "IIS Express worker process has stopped working".

I'm developing a project using ASP.NET MVC.

This is visual studio on may be a sample project.

Windows 7 Using.

My Steps 1 open project on Visual Studio 2012

My Steps 2 Build my Project

My Steps 3 Run my project

Error Details

Faulting application name: iisexpress.exe, version: 8.0.8418.0, time stamp: 0x4fbaa9e8
Faulting module name: ApiRd.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x52f26a34
Exception code: 0xc000041d
Fault offset: 0x0000239c
Faulting process id: 0x12ec
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf2d83a6972b10
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Obqcics\ApiRd.dll
Report Id: e4f689ae-9976-11e3-9426-e840f2ac7e6e
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Answer (score 2):

Close out Visual Studio completely, then check your system tray and stop any instances of IIS Express that might be running. Re-start Visual Studio, create a new MVC project based on one of the standard templates. Check the properties to ensure it's set to use IIS Express, and then run it. If you don't get the same error, check any custom code your might have in the troubled project's Global.asax.cs (or .vb) file. Put debug points on the first line of every method you have code in (Application_Start, etc.). Step over each line and see where it breaks.

If you don't have any custom code in there, close out VS and clean the ASP.NET temp directories. Do a restart, and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to have been caused by AVG antivirus.

I was able to solve by uninstalling AVG antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your ASP.NET MVC project. 
Select '**Properties**' option.
Go to **'Web' settings** and choose option **'Use Visual Studio Development Server'** in **'Servers' category**.

Now try to run the application, it will execute.

Answer (score 0):

Run your visual studio and your browser as Administrator

Answer (score 0):

I had default chrome as a default browser and was getting the same issue while debugging. I changed the default browser in visual studio to Internet Explorer and then tried again. I was able to run my project successfully. Hope this may help.